# SEQUENCE in SQL Server 2014, log who call next value

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have a sequence in sql server, is there any way to log which user call the sentence:

```
SELECT (NEXT VALUE FOR dbo.MySequence)
```

Comment: Not easily. I am struggling to find where a real world usage of this would be helpful.

Comment: One way I can thing of making a work around here is to create a procedure to GetNextSequence or similar. Then you could get the next value for your sequence and insert a row into an audit table that would track "whodunnit"

Comment: yes I can do that, but I was trying something like using extended events or database triggers

Comment: You might be able to do that with extended events. I have never tried capturing information for a sequence. A trigger isn't going to help because a sequence is not a table. It is a different type of object.

Comment: My curiosity is piqued - if you're able to get the data, what will you do with it?